# How to compile a single TS file with tsconfig? Optionally in ts-node?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to compile a single ts file and pass in tsconfig.json. `tsc -p tsconfig.json demo.ts` Here is my config file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@ds-editor/*": ["packages/@ds-editor/*"],
      "@ds/editor": ["packages/ds-editor"]
    },
    "typeRoots": ["./types", "./node_modules/@types"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": false
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"]
}
```

In TS document, it says `paths is only available in tsconfig` and `When input files are specified on the command line, tsconfig.json files are ignored.`
So I'm wondering how to make the two fit together. Also I'm trying to use `ts-node` if possible, has similar problem on the compilation part.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to make use of the `files` property in your tsconfig.

```
...
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"],
  "files": [
      "path/to/demo.ts"
  ],
}
```

Then compile with:

```
tsc -p tsconfig.json
```

[TS Config Examples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#examples)

Comment: It is worth noting that: _The "exclude" property defaults to excluding the node_modules, bower_components, jspm_packages and <outDir> directories when not specified_.

Comment: Hi! I tried this and have my target ts file in `files` property. But somehow tsc still compiles all my files...

Comment: @Mengo, are you sure? It worked for me... I specified `files: ["./src/demo.ts"]` with a bunch of other ts files in `src` and it only output `demo.js`.

Comment: Yeah... I tried both `-p `and `--project`. To be precise I did `tsc -p demo.json` and have `files` property set an absolute path to `demo.ts`. Not sure why...

Comment: Are you sure you using the correct json file? Should it not be `tsc -p tsconfig.json`?

Comment: I copied `tsconfig.json` to `demo.json` and added `file` attribute.

Comment: Does it has to be called `tsconfig.json` or can be any json file?

Comment: I think because you import other files in demo.ts file so those other files will be compiled to js too.

Comment: @Mengo Not sure if that's your case, but using `files` was also compiling all my files, but I realized I was extending another tsconfig files having `"include": ["src"]`. I was able to fix it by simply specifying the file path in `includes` instead of `files` which was overwriting the parent `includes` property.